# Attaching text to the twitter sharing link

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm trying to figure out how I can output the string of text `Try this recipe` at the beginning of this twitter sharing function. So when you click the button to share it will say "Try this recipe" then have the url etc. Thank you.

```
function load_twitter() {
    var load = window.open('http://twitter.com/share?url='+ window.location.href +'&via=atsbyvermouth','','scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=450,width=650,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple, just add this `text=Try this recipe&` at first, i.e.

```
function load_twitter() { 
    window.open('http://twitter.com/share?text=Try this recipe&url='+ window.location.href +'&via=atsbyvermouth','','scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=450,width=650,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no'); 
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8nTk5/1/).

Comment: Thank you Sheikk it worked great! I'm not too familiar with Javascript yet.

Comment: You are welcome but the variable `text` is a get parameter here, anyway. :-)