# How to return the onclick function is result to href in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Now, my code to share on twitter looks like this :

```
<span class='st_twitter_large' st_via="mediajobscom" st_url="" onclick="window.location.href=myURL;" displayText='Tweet'></span>
```

And the script i use :

```
<script>
var myURL = document.URL+"&featuredid={$listing.Title}&featured=true";                    
</script>
```

When i click on the share button now, it reloads the page and it adds my parameters  featuredid and featured.I need to return this value to the st_url="" so that i can share the new resulted link which contains the parameters.

Thanks a lot for your help! 
Hamza

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291950/attaching-text-to-the-twitter-sharing-link/12292283#12292283), you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var myURL = document.URL+"&featuredid={$listing.Title}&featured=true";`

Replace the st_url attribute in the st_twitter_large class using javascript:

`document.getElementsByClassName("st_twitter_large")[0].setAttribute("st_url", myURL);`

Comment: I had used the code instead that Sheikh shared, but i don't know how to put my variable as the required url, please have a look : <script>
var myURL = document.URL+"&featuredid={$listing.Title}&featured=true"; 
     function load_twitter() { 
    
    window.open('http://twitter.com/share?text=Try this recipe&url='+ window.location.href=myURL +'&via=atsbyvermouth','','scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=450,width=650,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no'); 

}      
     </script>

Comment: Sorry i didn't got at first what you were pointing to, as i don't have much experience with javascript.But trying your solution was the easiest way for me.Thanks a lot for your help!! You really saved my day!! :-)